# Looking for room booking diary webapp

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a web app that will allow for authorised people to book a room (or any resource for that matter) and prevent double-booking.

I need...

- One-off reservations. (2013-12-25, 10pm-6am.)
- Repeating weekly reservations. (Every Tuesday, 7pm-2am)
- Repeating monthly reservations. (2nd Sunday of the month, 9am-1pm)
- Allow many authorised users to add, edit and view entries without sharing passwords.
- An API to read the data from C# code.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [Calpendo](http://www.calpendo.com).

You can give it rules about who's allowed to book, when and for how long. It includes a double booking rule, although it's configurable so you can choose whether double bookings are allowed and even how many at once (think of a computer room with 10 shared computers in there where you'd want to allow 10 simultaneous bookings).

You can also associate "projects" with bookings if you want. This will let you limit bookings by project and also give you project-based reporting of booking usage.

There's no API at the moment, but there's a webdav/caldav API on the way.

Disclaimer: I work for [Spring Solutions](http://www.springsolutions.co.uk) who develop Calpendo.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Google account for it so that it has its own calendar.  That satisfies your reservation requirements, allows for invitations to be sent, etc.  Its users would need to honor its busy times rather than booking over them, but that gets you most of the way there.  There is also a Google Calendar API.

It's not the perfect solution, but it's probably among the least labor-intensive ones.

Comment: Thank you, but the double-booking prevention is the main bullet point I need. I could live without much of the others.